# Android O: what will be effect of the new version of Android on Location Updates?

Tags: android, location, android-fusedlocation, android-8.0-oreo

My app is currently using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` to receive location updates from FusedLocationApi. How will my location updates be affected in Android O? I went through the documentation given in this link: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#broadcasts.
But I am still not sure about my situation. I have no foreground or background services to receive location updates from FusedLocationApi. I have registered a broadcast receiver which keeps listening to any updates from FusedLocationApi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on if your broadcast receiver runs in the background or foreground. If it is part of an Activity, then location updates should works as before. On the foreground in this context should be interpreted as user visible, either by an Activity or a foreground service (visible as notification).

Comment: My BroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver. It starts a service in background every time a location update is received.

Comment: Your broadcast receiver is running somewhere too and the question is whether this is a foreground or background context.

Comment: It is in background.

Comment: You'll need to change that to not be affected by the Android O background location limits. See here: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-location-limits.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your app is affected in several ways. You will receive updates only few times in a hour regardless how you setup the location request. In addition you can't start a service from your receiver, you can do it only if the service is in foreground or the user excluded your app from battery opmizations. So if you really need frequent updates, you need to start a foreground service in order to keep your app in foreground. The service can be "empty" (no work), you can keep your current design, the goal is just to keep your app in foreground

Comment: Can you please elaborate on " In addition you can't start a service from your receiver, you can do it only if the service is in foreground or the user excluded your app from battery optimizations." I have not read about this. Also, can you share me the link where you found this information. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Almost missed this point. Is there a limitation on how many times I can start the service as a foreground service from a background receiver?

Comment: No, no limit, the important thing is to start it in foreground.

Comment: @greywolf82 "In addition you can't start a service from your receiver, you can do it only if the service is in foreground": you can, by using PendingIntent.getForegroundService or by using Context.startForegroundService.